# Fitting an absolute-value formula to a collection of points in the plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, absolute-value, interpolation

I need an equation to satisfy the following data points and I can't come up with anything. I believe it needs an absolute value as that changes the slope of the line.

Best yet: $y=2x-|x-4|$

Points are: $(1,1)$; $(2,3)$; $(3,5)$; $(4,7)$; $(5,8)$; $(6,10)$; $(7,11)$; $(8,12)$; $(9,13)$; $(10,14)$; $(11,15)$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this really qualifies as a puzzle. You might be better off posting this questions on [math.se] SE; I've flagged it to ask the mods to migrate it there.

Comment: Oh yay my boredom is finally relevant https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p6nqvyekcl

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if the goal is to find a function $y(x)$ which fits EXACTLY, or approximately.

If exactly is required :
$$\begin{cases}
y=2x-1 &\text{ if } x\leq 4 \\
y=8 &\text{ if } x=5 \\  
y=x+4 &\text{ if } x\geq 6 
\end{cases} \quad\to\quad y=8+(2x-9)H(4.5-x)+(x-4)H(x-4.5)$$
$H$ is the Heaviside step function.

If the fourth point is $(5,9)$ instead of $(5,8)$ a simpler form is : $$y=\frac{1}{2}(3+3x-|x-5|)$$.

If an approximate fit is wanted :

A usual regression calculus is sufficient, for example with the function $y=ax^2+by+c$. This is a linear regression for $a, b, c $ which leads to :
$$a\simeq -0.0711$$
$$b\simeq 2.226$$
$$c\simeq -1.085$$
The graph of the function $y=ax^2+by+c$ is shown :

[image]

This was computed with the fourth point $(5,8)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant $(5, 9)$ instead of $(5, 8)$, then
$$
y = 1.5(x + 1) - 0.5|x - 5|
$$
works. Otherwise,
\begin{align*}
y &= 1.5(x + 1) - 0.5|x - 5| + 0.5\min\bigl(|x - 5| - 1, 0\bigr) \\
  &= 1.5(x + 1) - 0.5\bigl(1 + \bigl||x - 5| - 1\bigr|\bigr)
\end{align*}
hits them all.